# is Multicast programming possible in android 4.0.3?

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, multicast

I'm developing an Android application which can communicate to the java server using multicast socket. I've developed same application successfully in java only, but i am getting problem when I'm using the same code in android. 
I found a code on Google thread reporting that android doesn't support multicastSocket. 
Please tell me how can we apply multicasting in android ? 
Is Multicast programming possible in android ?
Please provide some useful links..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in android to use multicast socket. you may refer to this class for android

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html